How to train a new attribute for a transformer object detector?
I have a transformer object detector, the outputs are tracked object bboxes in a video, which contains attributes like location (x,y,z), dimension (h,w,l).
I want the transformer to learn a new attribute of the detected objects, for example, the colors.
Suppose my object detector is already perfect in providing the locations and dimensions, I don't want to reduce its performance when i train the new attribute, how can I do it?  Thanks in advance.
